# Beamer overlay for plain text

Tags: beamer, overlays

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> abc
\item<2-> def
\end{itemize}
\begin{definition}<3->
ghi
\end{definition}
<4->jkl
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I want the plain text "jkl" to appear last, after the two "items" and one "definition". But what I did here didn't work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to provide some command to make the text 'variable'. Here, the obvious option is `\uncover`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> abc
\item<2-> def
\end{itemize}
\begin{definition}<3->
ghi
\end{definition}
\uncover<4->{jkl}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You could also consider `\only`, but it would alter vertical spacing so is unlikely to be what you want.